# Neo.ClientError.Statement.EntityNotFound

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I just created a new folder name-Test and started Neo4j server.
When i run the below script, i get the error - "Neo.ClientError.Statement.EntityNotFound"
and a message  "Node with id 0"

```
start root=node(0)
create
    (tatham {Name:'Tatham'}),
    (tom {Name:'Tom'}),
    (pat {Name:'Pat'}),
    (chrissy {Name:'Chrissy'}),
    (sailing {Name:'Sailing'}),
    (mtb {Name:'MTB'}),
    (rowing {Name:'Rowing'}),
    (tennis {Name:'Tennis'}),
    root-[:HAS_USER]->tatham,
    root-[:HAS_USER]->tom,
    root-[:HAS_USER]->pat,
    root-[:HAS_USER]->chrissy,
    tatham-[:FRIEND]->tom,
    tom-[:FRIEND]->pat,
    tatham-[:FRIEND]->chrissy,
    tatham-[:LIKES]->sailing,
    tatham-[:LIKES]->mtb,
    tom-[:LIKES]->sailing,
    pat-[:LIKES]->mtb,
    tom-[:LIKES]->rowing,
    pat-[:LIKES]->tennis,
    chrissy-[:LIKES]->mtb,
    chrissy-[:LIKES]->sailing
```

Can you kindly help me hot to fix this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A @WilliamLyon indicated:

- A new DB has no nodes, and therefore has no node with the ID of 0.
- The `START` clause is now deprecated.

You are apparently using a very old version of neo4j. If possible, you should install the latest version.

In addition:

- Nodes now must always be specified within parentheses.

Try the following, instead, which should work with your version of neo4j as well as the latest versions:

```
  CREATE
    (tatham {Name:'Tatham'}),
    (tom {Name:'Tom'}),
    (pat {Name:'Pat'}),
    (chrissy {Name:'Chrissy'}),
    (sailing {Name:'Sailing'}),
    (mtb {Name:'MTB'}),
    (rowing {Name:'Rowing'}),
    (tennis {Name:'Tennis'}),
    (root)-[:HAS_USER]->(tatham),
    (root)-[:HAS_USER]->(tom),
    (root)-[:HAS_USER]->(pat),
    (root)-[:HAS_USER]->(chrissy),
    (tatham)-[:FRIEND]->(tom),
    (tom)-[:FRIEND]->(pat),
    (tatham)-[:FRIEND]->(chrissy),
    (tatham)-[:LIKES]->(sailing),
    (tatham)-[:LIKES]->(mtb),
    (tom)-[:LIKES]->(sailing),
    (pat)-[:LIKES]->(mtb),
    (tom)-[:LIKES]->(rowing),
    (pat)-[:LIKES]->(tennis),
    (chrissy)-[:LIKES]->(mtb),
    (chrissy)-[:LIKES]->(sailing);
```

The `root` node will be created automatically the first time it is encountered by the query, and then re-used.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the first line of your Cypher query: `start root=node(0)`. That statement is saying "find a Node with id 0", however if you haven't inserted any data yet there is no Node to find, thus the error.

`start` has been deprecated and is no longer required so you can just remove it.